# How to : Run an App WITHOUT a taskbar button ?

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons

In the MS Windows GUI - say Win XP for definiteness, I want a GUI app to run WITHOUT a taskbar button-icon (while its main window is not minimized). Is there a 3-rd party "tweaker" or combination of tweaks to achieve that goal ? Either preventing Windows to create a taskbar button when launhcing and initializing the application, or removing the button afterwards would be acceptable.

Be it added that I am aware of several "tweakers" that can capture a taskbar button while a window is being minimized and "divert" it to the notification area (AKA system tray) : this is NOT what I am seeking ! I want NO icon or button whatsoever for the selected Windows app.

In addition, I wish such tweak to work as well for "Win16" applications, that being run by Windows in the so-called "NTVDM" system (itself a queer beast inside of MS Win32).

Any ideas ? Among reasons why this is needed are apps which run always on top, never minimized such as a clock. There is zero reason to use up valuable taskbar real estate for a button which I will NEVER have any use for !  Example of a 16-bit Win app like that is the round clock that was written by the good guys at Microsoft, in Windows 95 times, to show-off (then new) non-rectangular windows.

Comment: first google entry: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/stealth-or-hide-running-program-from-appearing-in-taskbar-or-traybar/

Comment: @SimonS: that blog entry looks like nothing to do with my question. Please heed, I am not wanting to hide an app"s main window and/or its respective taskbar icon, what I need is to "zap" the taskbar icon altogether, i.e. have the Windows window-manager destroy it or not create it in the first place.